# Why isn't my view updating when I change viewmodel properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `DataGrid` based view of `Appointment` objects. When the user double-clicks a row, I open a model window to view/edit the clicked appointment. I do that through the command below, bound to the `LeftDoubleClick` mouse event. The binding works and the command is correctly invoked.

```
_doubleClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<AppointmentRowViewModel>(async p =>
    {
        if (BossViewModel.ShowModalCommand.CanExecute(null))
        {
            var modal = new AppointmentFormWindow();
            await modal.ViewModel.Populate(p.Id, Cts.Token);
            BossViewModel.ShowModalCommand.Execute(modal);

        }
    },
    p => true
);
```

The selected item and command parameter, `p`, is an `AppointmentRowViewModel`, a purely presentation model for an `AppointmentDto` object, with properties only and zero logic.

`BossViewModel` is the viewmodel of the `MainWindow`, responsible for managing which view is displayed, and in this case, for displaying modals and messageboxes. I placed this responsibility here because messageboxes need an owner window, and this is the sole viewmodel that is aware of its view. It just made sense to also open and manage other windows from the `MainWindowViewModel`.

So `DoubleClickCommand` creates an instance of the window it wants opened, and the XAML for that window, in this case, assigns an `AppointmentFormViewModel` to it. The command calls `Populate` on that viewmodel to load an appointment and map it to that viewmodel:

```
public override async Task Populate(int? entityId = null, CancellationToken cancellation = new CancellationToken())
{
        if (entityId.HasValue)
        {
            await _apptService.Load(entityId.Value, this, cancellation);
        }
        IsInitialized = true;
        OnAllPropertiesChanged();
}
```

where I use `INotifyPropertyChanged` like this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnAllPropertiesChanged()
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
}
```

Then `BossViewModel.ShowModalCommand` looks like this:

```
_showModalCommand = new DelegateCommand<IModal>(async modal =>
    {
        modal.ViewModel.BossViewModel = this;
        modal.ShowDialog();
    },
    a => !ModalOpen
);
```

Everything works fine, the appointment is loaded from the DB, mapped to its viewmodel, which is already assigned to the `AppointmentGridWindow`. The modal opens, but its viewmodel is fully populated, non of the form fields are updated to reflect viewmodel property values. It is as if I was creating a new appointment.

All my data bindings use "Mode=TwoWay<strike>, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True</strike>", so I would expect setting a value on the viewmodel and raising `PropertyChanged` would update the view element, but the view remains all totally blank.

**UPDATE:** Here is a XAML excerpt from the view than remains blank. The viewmodel properties they are bound to all have valid values, because the form works fine for capture only.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:AppointmentFormViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
.....
<TextBlock Text="Topic:" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Topic, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock Text="Venue: " />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Venue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock Text="Start Date: " />
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<ComboBox IsEditable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding TimeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=StartTime, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock Text="End Date: "/>
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding EndDate}" />
<ComboBox IsEditable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TimeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=EndTime, Mode=TwoWay}" />
....
<DataGrid x:Name="TheList" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Attendees}"....>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding GivenName}" Header="Given Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FamilyName}" Header="Family Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Phone}" Header="Phone" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EMail}" Header="Email" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Position}" Header="Position" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrgName}" Header="Org." />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BranchName}" Header="Branch" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

**PROBLEM RESOLVED:** Suddenly, after much code inspection, editing for the above code excerpts, and some Git rollbacks, the view in question now populates properly. I think it was making the bindings `TwoWay`, but when I first did that, it didn't work. Something else was wrong that while doing all the fiddling around for answering the comments below, I somehow restored something to a proper state.

Thank you all, the commenters, for your advice and help.

Comment: Post (part of) the XAML, and do look in the Output window for binding errors.

Comment: Make sure you are calling your UI notification method from the UI thread. There is a lot of async going on here, and UI changes can get lost if not executed on the UI thread.

Comment: Also, the application output window in VS may show some binding errors that aren't throwing exceptions. That may be useful info.

Comment: "All my data bindings use Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True" -- you don't have the faintest idea what either of those flags actually means, do you?

Comment: Where is the code that set the `DataContext` of your view? Maybe the `DataContext` is not what you think it is. And another thing: Your `Populate` method doesn't actually set any properties (other than `IsInitialized`). I realize you only provide snippets, but are you sure you properties actually *are* changed?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I do not take kindly to insults based on arrogant assumptions. I have read  on those binding properties several times, the latest a few hours ago when I discovered this problem. I am not sure of the effect of `TwoWay` in an MVVM vs. code-behind scenario, but I no the latter, and used the property as an experiment to try to get my viewmodel to update my view as well as vice versa. The other property I unserstand to mean the the UI will be notified when the source property, i.e. the viewmodel property in this case, raises `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: `Mode=TwoWay` means the *target* (UI control property) value is copied back to source (viewmodel) when target value changes. `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` causes the [`Binding.SourceUpdated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.sourceupdated(v=vs.110).aspx) event to be raised when a value is transferred from the binding target to the binding source. Are you handling the `SourceUpdated` event on all of your bindings? That's its name, `SourceUpdated`. Are you explicitly giving them an event handler?

Comment: @DirkVollmar I stated in my question that the XAML for the view sets the `DataContext`, e.g. `<Window.DataContext><vm:AppointmentFormViewModel /></Window.DataContext>`. I know that context is set because I see its ctor execute when I instantiate the window. The `Populate` method passes `this` to a `Load` method that assigns values to all the properties. Once again, I did state in my question that the values are properly assigned and there is nothing wrong with the viewmodel, only the view that is not updating when the viewmodel is populated.

Comment: Thank you, @EdPlunkett. It appears I missed some stuff in my reading, but learning the "source" is whatever object, of any kind, the bound property gets its value from, I assumed a notification would be fired when that source was updated from anywhere, not just the target. I don't believe I need that binding property nor the event handler then, because I don't have any problems transferring values from target to source. My problem is the opposite. I can capture a new appointment with zero anomalies or errors. I just cannot read that captured appointment and let the view know it should show it.

Comment: @KelsonBall Very good point. My first concern on that list is the modal blocking the UI thread while it is open, then there are a few other similar threading concerns. I'm trying very hard to maintain an always responsive UI, is why there is so much async. And once you make one method async, it's async all the way down. The `Populate` and notification calls are, I assume, on the command's thread, and I don't know what effect that has, or what to do about it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Posted a XAML excerpt from the view that won't update. I removed cosmetic attributes like sizes etc. to keep it brief and to the point. Onl;y yhe `DataGrid` bindings are not `TwoWay`, but they are read only.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only made all the bindings `TwoWay` just before asking this question, and by then something else was wrong. I rolled back, and made them all `TwoWay` again, with success.

So, the answer is, bindings you want updated when the viewmodel changes must be two-way, e.g:

```
Text="{Binding Topic, Mode=TwoWay}"
```